# apostrophes coming in as �

Tags: html, encoding, character-encoding

I am reading in HTML from a file and displaying it on a web page:

When I look at in the source I see:

```
The Club’s summer junior programs
```

but it shows up as:

```
The Club�s summer junior program
```

What is happening here and why the `�` is showing up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you set the proper encoding of the html page?

Read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_encoding) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/charset.html).

Comment: can you give me an example:  i put:

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

at the top of the page but it made no difference

Comment: Didn't you have a fixed/not utf-8 character encoding set in your browser settings?This "bug" is presents in different machine? Do you have a public page we can see it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you (or someone close to you) is copy/pasting from Word and you are seeing the webby effects of word's [not so] smart quotes. The work around is to set the character encoding to utf-8 or windows-1252.

Comment: how do i set character encoding

Comment: i tried adding: 

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

but no difference

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely a character encoding issue. It means the page says it has X encoding, but actually it has Y.

Answer (score 0):

A very interesting read by Joel: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html about this topic, definitively a must read if you didn't already read this.

It explains pretty well why these problems occur, how they came to be and how to avoid it :).

Answer (score 0):

May be you have copied text from a work editor, like MS Word, which changes quotes to open quotes and closed quotes characters. When such a text is copied to a text file, it gives these problems.

A simple solution can be to type these quotes again in the text editor.